# Add favicon on php echo page

Tags: php, echo, favicon

I just created a simple php form on a HTML Website. All is working and good, but I'd like to add an favicon on the echo page... I'm using this code actually:

```
    <?php $name = $_POST['demo-name'];
    $email = $_POST['demo-email'];
    $message = $_POST['demo-message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@gmx.net";
    $subject = "Message from ...";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "<body style='background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; font-family:arial; font-size:20px; padding-top: 100px' align='center' >" . " " . "Thank You! </br> </br><a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#f3bd46;'> Return to ...</a></body>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't see where you try to implement a favicon. A favicon is defined in the html-head, more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use

Answer (score 0):

You should include the HTML code to your favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive that by 'echo page' you mean php page after form submit that consists of code that you shared.
That page doesn't need to be all php code, so instead of echoing html you can do pure html below php mail code.
So that php file would look like this, favicon is in html head.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['demo-name'];
    $email = $_POST['demo-email'];
    $message = $_POST['demo-message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@gmx.net";
    $subject = "Message from ...";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <style>
   body{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
   }
   a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f3bd46;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    Thank You! <br/><br/>
    <a href='index.html'> Return to ...</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have a valid answer, to make things a bit more clear, you can try removing the eco part and replace it with the following example:

```
<?php
$output  = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>';
$output .= '<html><head><title></title>';
$output .= '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">';
$output .= '<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">';
$output .= '</head>';
$output .= '<body style="background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; font-family:arial; font-size:20px; padding-top: 100px" align="center">';
$output .= 'Thank You! </br></br><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:#f3bd46;"> Return to ...</a></body>';
$output .= '</html>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Please note that if the Source Code appearance is important to you, you may want to make some adjustments to the code, like adding new lines and tabs with \n\t as well as changing and escaping quotes where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it's not just about creating a few tags and adding a favicon.ico file. You should instead use tools such as the Favicon Generator here: http://realfavicongenerator.net/

It generates and previews your favicon for Android, iOS, MacOS, Windows Phone, etc.